# Everyday GC is running on same time

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection

In my server everyday 3:00AM GC is running and Heapspace is filling in a flash.

This causing site outage. ANY inputs?

following are my JVM settings.I am using JBOSS server.

-Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms1524m -Xmx1524m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000  -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.100.140 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

Any suggestions really helpful..

Comment: Do you have anything scheduled to run at 3 am?

Comment: No..we monitored the logs and no other scheduler is running..Even I tested like I restarted the server at 2:30AM so that heap will cleared.up to 3:00AM the heap is upto 400MB. At 3:00 AM suddenly GC is running and all the space is filled up in a flash.

Comment: Below are the gc.log output of GC failure.Any Inputs are really helpful. 34277.999: 34284.652: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
34284.758: [GC 34284.758: [ParNew (promotion failed): 523392K->523392K(523840K), 0.8095230 secs]34285.568: [CMS34286.158: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.662/1.506 secs]
 (concurrent mode failure): 998786K->984155K(1036288K), 6.4504900 secs] 1517815K->984155K(1560128K), 7.2603450 secs]

Answer (score 4):

(This turned out somewhat long; there is an actual suggestion for a fix at the end.)

Very very briefly, garbage collection when you use -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC works like this:

All objects are allocated in the so-called young generation. This is typically a couple of hundred megs up to a gig in size, depending om VM settings, number of CPU:s and total heap size. The young generation is collected in a stop-the-world pause, followed by a parallel (multiple CPU) compacting (moving objects) collection. The young generation is sized so as to make this pause reasonably large.

When objects have survived (are still reachable) young gen they get *promoted* to "old-gen" (old generation).

The old generation is where -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC kicks in. In the default mode (without -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) when the old generation becomes full the entire heap is collected and compacted (moving around, eliminating fragmentation) at once in a stop-the-world copy. That pause will typically be longer than young-gen pauses because the *entire* heap is involved, which is bigger.

With CMS (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) the work to compact the old generation is mostly concurrent (meaning, running in the background with the application *not* paused). This work is also *not* compacting; it works more like malloc()/free() and you are subject to fragmentation.

The main upside of CMS is that when things work well, you avoid long pause times that are linear in the size of the heap, because the main work is cone concurrently (there are some stop-the-world steps involved but they are supposed to usually be short).

The two primary downsides are that:

- You are subject to fragmentation because old-gen is not compacted.
- If you don't finish a concurrent collection cycle before old-gen fills up, or if fragmentation prevents allocation, the resulting full collection of the entire heap is *not* parallel as it is with the default collector. I..e, only one CPU is used. That means that when/if you *do* hit a full garbage collection, the pause will be *longer* than it would have been with the default collector.

Now... your logs. "Concurrent mode failure" is intended to convey that the concurrent mark/sweep work did not complete in time for another young-gen GC that needs to promote surviving objects into the old generation. The "promotion failed" is rather that during promotion from young-gen to old-gen, an object was unable to be allocated in old-gen due to fragmentation.

Unless you are hitting a true bug in the JVM, the sudden increase in heap usage is almost certainly from your application, JBoss, or some external entity acting on your application. So I can't really help with that. However, what is likely happening is a combination of two things:

1. The spike in activity is causing an increase in heap usage too quick for the concurrent collection to complete in time.
2. Old-gen is too fragmented, causing problems especially when the old-gen is almost full.

I should also point out now that the default behavior of CMS is to try to postpone concurrent collections as long as possible (yet not *too* long) for performance reasons. The later it happens, the more efficient (in terms of CPU usage) the collection is. However, a trade-off is that you're increasing the risk of not finishing in time (which again, will trigger a full GC and a long pause). It should also (I have not made empirical tests here, but it stands to reason) result in fragmentation being a greater concern; basically the more full old-gen is when an object is promoted, the greater is the likelyhood that the object's promotion will worsen fragmentation concerns (too long to go into details here).

In your case, I would do two things:

1. Keep figuring out what is causing the activity. I would say it's fairly unlikely that it is a GC/JVM bug.
2. Re-configure the JVM to trigger concurrent collection cycles earlier in order to avoid the heap every becoming so full that fragmentation becomes a particularly huge concern, and giving it more time to complete in time even during your sudden spikes of activity.

You can accomplish (2) most easily be using the JVM options

- `-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75`
- `-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly`

in order to explicitly force the JVM to kick start a CMS cycle at a certain level of heap usage (in this example 75% - you may need to change that; the lower the percentage, the earlier it will kick in).

Note that depending on what your live size is (the number of bytes that are in fact live and reachable) in your application, forcing an earlier CMS cycle may also require that you increase your heap size to avoid CMS running constantly (not a good use of CPU).

Comment: Scode..Thank you very much..It given me an complete view on GC. I will test this and will post you the update. Another Thing is sometimes when the Normal GC run's our systems threads are increasing rapidly.. Any suggestions ??

Comment: By normal do you mean the frequent young-generation collections? Are you saying you see a spike of threads each time, followed by a decrease until the next one? If so, that sounds to me like a build-up resulting from whatever worked was "queued" (e.g., on an incoming tcp socket, accept() backlog, etc) for the duration of the GC. But this is heavy speculation since I know nothing of the situation.

Comment: we also observed that when gc ran CPU usage suddenly increased to 90 and it's coming down after the gc finished the work.This not for all young-generation collections only for some of the collections.Is there any configurations am I missing?

Comment: The description of young generation gc is not correct. The Young generation gc is a copying collector. All mutator threads are stopped, all live objects in eden and from space are copied into to-space and some objects might be promoted to tenured space. Then the threads are restarted. Note that a copying collector is by default a compacting collector.